# Date#toLocaleDateString Chrome vs Electron

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, localization, electron

Considering the same javascript application running on:

1. Browsers (mostly Chrome): `Intl.DateTimeFormat().format(new Date) // "05/01/2018"`
2. [Electron](https://electronjs.org/): `Intl.DateTimeFormat().format(new Date) // "2018-1-5"`

we have a list of items and each of these items has a field: `created date` which basically displays a date in locale format:

```js
const items = [
  {
    title: 'I am the Title',
    createdDate: new Date(),
    id: 'foobazID'
  }
];

const render = item => (`
  <table class="table table-striped" id="${item.id}">
    <tr>
      <th>ID:</th><td>${item.id}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Title:</th><td>${item.title}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Created At:</th><td>${item.createdDate.toLocaleDateString()}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
`);

document
  .getElementById('view')
  .innerHTML = items.reduce((res, item) => res.concat(render(item)), '')
;
```

```css
#view {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section id="view">
</section>
```

now, considering both applications running on the same machine, we're getting two different date time formats:

#### Electron:

[image: Electron Version]

#### Google Chrome:

[image]

What can we do to have same formatting output?

Answer (score 1):

You may first want to run the following statement in the Electron and Chrome respective DevTools console to spot any difference in the default date time format:

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions()
```

Chances are that the `locale` property has a different value (`"en"`, `"en-UK"`, `"en-US"`, etc.) based on some browser settings...

Then, add explicitly the proper `locale` as a parameter to [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat), `"en"` for instance:

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat("en").format(new Date)
```